# How to npm install client and server project dependencies with single command?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have a backend and frontend parts of the project in single root folder:

```
./app/ - backend files and folders
./app/forntend/ - front end files and folders
```

in my app folder I have package.json with scripts and backend dependencies, installation script here is: `"install": "npm i && cd ./frontend && npm i"`, I also have package.json in frontend with its own denendencies
when I run installation script it enters into infinite loop of installs, which I have to terminate manually.
Is there way to have a single installation script in `package.json`?

Comment: I know this is not the recommended solution, but just to drop an idea. Our project has a similar structure and we use a shell script to run the npm commands separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by using **concurrently** npm module.
./app/ - backend files and folders
./app/forntend/ - front end files and folders

With concurrently installed in your root folder i.e. ./app/->backend, you can run multiple custom npm scripts. For example: you can create 2 separate scripts that are installing the dependencies (client-dependencies and server-dependencies) and then create install-all-deps script that will run both scripts one after another and install all deps in both directories.

```
{
    "scripts": {
    "server-dependencies": "npm install",
    "client-dependencies": "npm install --prefix forntend",
    "install-all-deps": "concurrently \"npm run server-dependencies\" \"npm run client-dependencies\""
    }
}
```

Link for Concurrently :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing concurrently part of server app then you will get an error concurrently is not installed. For that we have install concurrently first in following way

```
"scripts": {
    "install-server": "npm install",
    "install-client": "npm install --prefix forntend",
    "install": "npm install concurrently --save & concurrently \"npm run install-server\" \"npm run install-client\"",
    "start": "concurrently \"nodemon node_server/server.js\" \"npm run build\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

where

Use `&&` (double ampersand) for sequential execution.

Use `&` (single ampersand) for parallel execution.